# MySQL -Pentaho Error getting views from schema [null]

Tags: mysql, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

when trying to run Insert/Update or LookUp functions in Pentaho to get my SQL tables it shows me this error, anyone knows, how can I fix it?

```
Error getting views from schema [null]
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING TABLE_TYPE IN ('VIEW',null,null,null,null) ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SCH' at line 1
```

Comment: Can you share the query.. it will be helpful to debug.

Comment: Check your connection (Edit the connection, and test). When this is correct, press the SQL button. Does the error persist?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your Mysql version compatible to Pentaho version. You should get that in your Pentaho manual.

I downgraded from mysql 8.0 to 5.6/5.5 and on 5.6 its got resolved.

Comment: The query pentaho uses is compatible to mysql 5.6. I got resolved with this.